# Is it possible to assign the `--privileged=true` property to this container without stop the container?

Tags: docker

I run into this issue:
when I execute `systemctl`, there get error:

```
[root@eb00fc55c925 yum.repos.d]# systemctl start salt-minion
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
```

I found the solution run the container should add `--privileged=true`:

```
docker run -tid --name test --privileged=true centos /sbin/init

docker exec -it test /bin/bash
```

but now, in my container, I have installed some software and configured the network for it.
If I `exit` it, there will lost the network which is configured for it.

is it possible to assign the `--privileged=true` property to this container without lost network configured to it?

Comment: Commands like `systemctl` mostly just don't work in Docker at all.  You should run the command you're trying to run as the single foreground process in its own container instead.  (The `docker run` command you show will try to reconfigure a number of host-system things that you really don't want it to.)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do that because of how privileges are assigned by operating system.